# Variable lengths differ - fligner.test

Tags: r, statistics

I have the folloing a dataset like follows:

```
attack defense sp_attack sp_defense speed is_legendary
 60      62      63      80          60         0
 80      100    123      122         120        0
 39      52      43      60          65         0
 58      64      58      80          80         0
 90      90      85      125         90         1
100      90      125     85          90         1
106      150     70      194         120        1
100      100    100      100         100        1
90       85      75      115         100        1
```

From this dataset, I want to check if there is **heteroscedasticity between two groups: Legendary vs. Non legendary pokemons**. To do that, first I checked the normality of the data for the legendary and non legendary pokémon as follows:

```
# Shapiro-test for legendary and non legendari pokemon, hp comparison.
shapiro.test(df_net$hp[df_net$is_legendary==0])
shapiro.test(df_net$hp[df_net$is_legendary==1])
```

I´ve seen that in both cases the result is **not distributed normally.** Now, I´ve decided to carry out a Fligner test as follows:

```
fligner.test(hp[df_net$is_legendary==0] ~ hp[df_net$is_legendary==1], data = df_net)
```

However, I obtain the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = hp[df_net$is_legendary == 0] ~ : variable lengths differ (found for 'hp[df_net$is_legendary == 1]')
```

I guess that this is due to the number of observations of pokemon legendary different from non legendary but then how can I check the heteroscedasticity between this two groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for `fligner.test` is

```
fligner.test(x ~ group, data)
```

In your case the correct syntax would be (e.g for variable `sp_defense`)

```
fligner.test(sp_defense ~ is_legendary, data=df_net)
```

Comment: Hi, please, see post amended accordingly. I hope the information helps.

Comment: any suggestion?